# How to implement a TreeViewer such that root elements have multiple cells but child elements only a single cell?

Tags: eclipse, treeview, swt, jface

The following code shows how to create a `TreeViewer` with columns.

```
TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER);
Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();
tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

TreeViewerColumn treeViewerColumn = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.NONE);
TreeColumn trclmnNewColumn = treeViewerColumn.getColumn();
trclmnNewColumn.setWidth(100);
trclmnNewColumn.setText("New Column");

TreeViewerColumn treeViewerColumn_1 = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.NONE);
TreeColumn trclmnNewColumn_1 = treeViewerColumn_1.getColumn();
trclmnNewColumn_1.setWidth(100);
trclmnNewColumn_1.setText("New Column");
```

By default, if you expand a root element row, child element rows appear, and just like the root element rows, they are also divided into cells by the columns.

I would like to implement a `TreeViewer` such that child elements, unlike root elements, consist of a single cell that spans the width of the `TreeViewer`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one code snippet which shows how to span columns

[Table snippet: make text span multiple columns](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet239.java)

Also agree with Greg's answer, you can use [NatTable](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) as alternative to SWT TreeViewer. It also can render tree and more configurable than SWT TreeViewer

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the normal `TreeViewer` column support.

You could probably do it using an `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` where you have to draw the rows.

The [Eclipse Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) project has some additional grid and tree controls which might do what you want.